tiingo api - stock price fetching data
df= pdr.get_data_tiingo('GOOG', api_key='API-KEY')

Error :
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 df = pdr.get_data_tiingo('GOOG', api_key='606f0f6c7526f141b8f2200abc5db518debd74e5')

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py:120, in get_data_tiingo(*args, **kwargs)
    119 def get_data_tiingo(*args, **kwargs):
--> 120     return TiingoDailyReader(*args, **kwargs).read()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\tiingo.py:234, in TiingoDailyReader.read(self)
    232     finally:
    233         self.close()
--> 234 return pd.concat(dfs, self._concat_axis)

TypeError: concat() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I'm trying to fetch stock data from tiingo, but the error is popping up. How could I resolve it?
